# Theme for Specific Application WPS

Tags: 16.04, wps-office

Please help on this problem.

I used this command in my `wps-office-et.desktop` under `EXEC`

```
env GTK_THEME=/home/rk/.themes/vimix-light-laptop-ruby /usr/bin/et %f
```

Also, I tried this one

```
env GTK_THEME=vimix-light-laptop-ruby /usr/bin/et %f
```

Specifically, I use WPS office and I need to assign a specific theme for this WPS office.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and WPS Office

Realizing that when I run it as `root` instead of `normal user`, it will work. But for `normal user` it won't work.

Left WPS Spreadsheet with Black Cells are in normal user, the right WPS Spreadsheet with White Cells are in `root`

[image]

Comment: Do you have GNOME Tweaks? If not install it first (`sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`) and then check *exactly how* the name of the `vimix-light-laptop-ruby` appearing in the theme selection list in Tweaks.